# Как поменять местами ключ и значение в словаре?

Tags: python, словарь

Имеется словарь вида:

```
dict = {'a':'abc', 'b':'def', 'c':'ghi'}
```

Необходимо с помощью функции поменять местами ключ и значение у определенной пары.
нашел решение только для смены местами всех ключей и значений:

```
def reverse(k, v):
    for k, v in dict.items():
        dict[v] = k
reverse("b", "def")
print(dictionary)
```

Получаю такую ошибку: `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: Код, который вы показали, нерабочий от слова совсем (даже до ошибки RuntimeError дело не дойдёт)

Comment: А вообще если у одной определённой пары, то просто `словарь[словарь.pop(ключ)] = ключ` да и всё, не надо никакие циклы городить

Comment: Ошибка потому, что нельзя итерироваться по словарю и одновременно менять его. Непонятно всё-таки вы один ключ хотите поменять или все? У вас противоречие между сигнатурой функции и тем, что вы в ней делаете.

Comment: @CrazyElf хочу поменять одну пару (ключ, значение) местами.

Comment: Если не трудно поставьте галку, чтобы она стала зеленой, она ниже верхнего и нижнего треугольника.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict1 = {'a':'abc', 'b':'def', 'c':'ghi'}
dict2 = {v: k for k, v in dict1.items()}
print(dict2)
```

Можно даже так:

```
dict1 = {'a':'abc', 'b':'def', 'c':'ghi'}
dict1 = {v: k for k, v in dict1.items()}
print(dict1)
```